# How to see if an input is in a text file Python

Tags: python

So I am a student at a school learning the basics of python. I was given a project that I had to complete. I was given a text file with some names, if the user inputs the name that is in the text file then  it would print a message. If not then it would print another message saying something.

I have begun with my code, however, I cant seem to figure out how I can use the if and in command. Can someone give me some hints or solutions?

I have tried to put it in a list and then use the if and in command. It didnt work because of append. I dont know how to remove a word from a list. I can use slice method but it would seem too complicated.

```
a=input('Nickname idea: ')
classes=[]
c=open('class.txt')
while a:
 classes.append(a)
 print(classes)
 if a == c:
   print('That nickname is already taken!')
 else:
   print('Great name!')
 a=input('Nickname idea: ')
 classes.remove(classes[0])
```

the text file is named 
class.txt and the contents are
    Ali
    Alakazam
    Alberto
    AJ
    Bob
    Bobby
    Kat
    Katie
    Timmy
    Tim-tam
thanks.

Comment: After opening the file you will need to [read its contents](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) before you compare to the user's input.  If each name is on a separate line you can iterate over the lines. but you may need to [strip or split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) the line for the comparison to work.  Try some of the examples in [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) using your file.

Comment: Above code seemed to be working as your intentions when I tested out. It'd be nice if you can add some details to what you exactly are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have trouble understanding what you are exactly asking for, hopefully this resolves your question.

```
a = input('Nickname idea: ')
classes = []
c = open('class.txt')
txt = c.read()
while a:
    classes.append(a)
    print(classes)
    if a in txt:
        print('That nickname is already taken!')
    else:
        print('Great name!')
    a=input('Nickname idea: ')
    classes.remove(classes[0])
```

You can merely read the text file in to a string and check with the if-in statement.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was never taught how the read() worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
filename = 'name_list.txt'

with open(filename) as f_obj:
    usernames = f_obj.read()

name_to_check = input("Enter name: ")

if name_to_check in usernames:
    print("Hello, " + name_to_check)
else:
    print("Name not found.")
```

This is what you are looking for, from what you descirbed.

First step would be to open the file containing the list of whatever you want to check.
 Next we can run `read()` to assign all of that text to `usernames`.
From there you can run and `if name_to_check_ in usernames` and `else` to return seperate responses.