# How to check user input from a file in Python?

Tags: python, file, user-input

Hello I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
name1, password1
name2, password2,
name3, password3,
and so on...
```

I need to check if the user enters a name and password are the same stored in this file.
I looked at this answers but they did not help:
[answ1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031972/how-to-see-if-an-input-is-in-a-text-file-python)
[answ2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144311/how-do-i-check-user-input-from-a-file-in-python)
This is my code. If I put the correct name and password, the while loop still prompts me for user input:

```
name = input('Enter username: ')
password = input('Enter password: ')


with open('file.txt','r') as f: 
    data = f.readlines()
        
    for line in data:
        names =line.split(' ')[0]
        passwords = line.split(' ')[1]
      
        while name not in names or password not in passwords:
            name = input('Enter a valid username: ')
            password = input('Enter a valid password: ')
```

Comment: Are words separated by space or comma ?

Comment: Words are separated by commas

Comment: `line.split(' ')` is wrong so

Comment: `txt file that looks like this` - does it look exacly like this? name/password separated by a comma **and** a space? Lines 2+ end in a comma?

Comment: Yes. I one name and password per line.

Comment: @MarkusPe The second and subsequent lines end with comma. The first line does not. That's an unusual arrangement. Does this mean that passwords cannot contain commas? If so, you'll need to check for that on input. Wouldn't it be easier to just separate the name and password with a space (and, obviously, disallow spaces in names and passwords)

Comment: `line.split(' ')` This is wrong, because the fields are not separated by just a space; they are separated by a space and a comma.

Answer (score 1):

For now you're testing the user input against EVERY line: the inputs can't match every lines

You'd better store the pairs in a `dict`, that'll facilitate the verifications

---

#### Test both at once

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

credentials = {}
for line in data:
    name, password = line.strip().split(",")
    credentials[name] = password

name = input('Enter a username: ')
password = input('Enter a password: ')
while name not in credentials or credentials[name] != password:
    name = input('Enter a valid username: ')
    password = input('Enter a valid password: ')
```

#### Separate tests

```
name = input('Enter a username: ')
while name not in credentials:
    name = input('Enter a valid username: ')

password = input(f'Enter a password for user {name}: ')
while credentials[name] != password:
    password = input(f'Enter a valid password for user {name}: ')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I receive this error though:    name, password = line.strip().split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Probably because of the ending ',' ; try `line.strip().strip(',').split(",")` : the 1st strip will remove the endline, the 2nd the trailing comma. Alternatively, `name, password = line.strip().split(",")[0:2]` would work.

Comment: Can I just ask what is the meaning of this part of the code please? credentials[name] = password

Comment: @MarkusPe it assigns the value `password` to the key `name` in the dictionary `credentials`. Read tutorials about python dict

Answer (score 0):

Due to the inconsistent use of commas in the data file, you'll need to take some extra steps.

```
with open('file.txt') as indata:
    DB = dict(map(lambda e: e.rstrip(','), line.split()) for line in indata)
    while True:
        name = input('Enter username: ')
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        if DB.get(name) == password:
            break # username / password is valid
        print('Invalid username or password\a')
```

Answer (score -2):

With the help of fileinput. input() method, we can get the file as input and to can be used to update and append the data in the file by using fileinput. input() method. Return : Return the data of the file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).